# branch level deployments in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a requirement to deploy the release branch only by a particular user or group and the user should see only the release branches in bitbucket pipeline....

I am using bitbucket as CI.

Could you please help in this regard

Answer (score 0):

BitBucket allows a lot of customization for the actions to prevent by branch protection. To protect a branch:

1. Go to a repository in a project.
2. Choose Settings > Branch permissions.
3. Click Add permission.
4. In the Branches field, select either Branch name, Branch pattern, or Branching model.

Branch name - select an existing branch by name.

Branch pattern - specify a branch using branch pattern syntax for matching branch names.

Branching model - select the branch type to restrict access to.

5. Select the type of actions you want to prevent.

Branch deletion - prevents branch and tag deletion.

Rewriting history - prevents history rewrites on the specified branch(es) - for example by a force push or rebase.

Changes without a pull request - prevents pushing changes directly to the specified branch(es); changes are allowed only with a pull request.

All modifications - prevents pushes to the specified branch(es) and restricts creating new branches matching the specified branch(es) or pattern.

6. Optional: Add exemptions for any of the selected restrictions. Adding a user or group as an exemption means that it will not apply to them. This is not required; not adding any exemptions means the restriction will apply to everyone.
7. Click Create to finish.

Comment: Thanks for the details... I am looking only for deployments to a particular user to a specific branch... along side, I should restrict users from seeing other branches in pipeline.